# How to override this function to store data in DB?

Tags: sql, laravel

In BroadcastServiceProvider.php I've got data when user joins the channel and I would like to store it to DB. I am wondering how to override this storeUser() function to make it work (I've used this function before but it was in other circumstances).

```
   public function storeUser() {
       UserInfo::create([
      'ip' => Request::ip(),
      'name' =>  Auth::user()->name    
    ]);  
  }
```

BroadcastServiceProvider.php

```
   Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
        $ip = Request::ip();
        if (auth()->check()) { 
            return [
                'id' => $user->id,
                'ip' => $ip,
                'name' => $user->name
            ];
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where is the storeUser function defined?

Comment: @jfadich I've created UsersController.php for it.

Comment: Why not move it to a static method on the `UserInfo` model then calll `UserInfo:: storeUser()` both in the UsersController and the broadcast class.

Comment: @jfadich Could you be more specific? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the `UserInfo` model to have the `storeUser` method.

```
class UserInfo
{
   public static function storeUser() {
        UserInfo::create([
       'ip' => Request::ip(),
       'name' =>  Auth::user()->name    
   ]);  
}
```

Then you can call it in the broadcaster

```
Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
    $ip = Request::ip();
    if (auth()->check()) { 
        UserInfo::storeUser();
        return [
            'id' => $user->id,
            'ip' => $ip,
            'name' => $user->name
        ];
    }
});
```

You can also call it in the same way `UserInfo::storeUser();` in the users controller where ever you need it.

Comment: Did you mean storeUser instead recordUser?

Comment: Should I specify some route? Because for now, nothing happened.

Comment: I'm confused by what you're asking. I assumed it was working how you needed and you just wanted to add the store user call.

Comment: anyway Call to undefined method App\UserInfo::storeUser. This line   UserInfo::storeUser() gives an error. I added use App\UserInfo. Maybe there is something else I have to use? I am just trying to figure how it works.

Comment: Did you add the method to the model? That error is saying you didn't, or you named it something different.

Comment: It worked! I added use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth to UserInfo.php and you were right - the method was commented out. Thank you very much!